# Error when initializing firebase database in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am fairly new to react and I am trying out firebase. I am getting this error message

Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

and I have tried many things that didnt fix it.

This is how my config looks likes

```
export const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCrfLCYS7VuvvUVaEkfzYVdJJLeqVuZHQE",
    authDomain: "crudreac.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://crudreac.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "crudreac",
    storageBucket: "crudreac.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "116257347605"
  };
```

And this is how I am TRYING to initialize the databse

```
import { config } from './Config/config';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database'
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){   
    super(props);
    this.addNote = this.addNote.bind(this);
      this.app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
      console.log(firebase.app.name);
      this.db = this.app.database().ref().child('notes');
    this.state = {
      notes:[],
    }
  }
```

I am probably doing the initialization wrong, so if anyone could help me out I would apreciate it

I have already tried doing

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

But it didnt help

Comment: Is there another place where `initializeApp()` is being called? If this `if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}` didn't help, that seems likely. Check the complete stack trace of the error to see where it's coming from.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem at the end. Thank you very much @FrankvanPuffelen